# Manage more Rest paths once

Tags: java

I have this situation: I have more servers. On this servers a lot of applications are running. The applications work with other applications on other servers (I think this is a usual scenario for a lot production environments). All applications declare in her config files the rest paths where the other applications are. 
When a server change his name (do renewal of hardware or other things) or application A has to move from one server to another, the problem is that I have to change all paths of applications that use this application A. And this happens very often and is annoying

What I like to do is: 
- have a central place where I declare all REST paths that are needed of applications on Server A
- declare in applications on Server A to use this file/config/db to retrieve the value of the path

I think this to have the advantage that for every server I have to change only one time the paths.

Is there already a such solution? Or it gives other/better solution for this problems?

The most of applications are written in java (don't think that this has influence on a solution).

Comment: When as you say, machine change its name, application moves to other server, etc, Are you changing the REST target host ? or change the entire URL (the path also changes) ?

Comment: Principally the host name. The resources may remain the same

Comment: Why not consider Service Discovery (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery)? You can use Consul (https://www.consul.io/) or ZooKeeper or Eureka (from Netflix) and say 'bye bye' to any IP/hostname hardcoding.

Comment: I would suggest the more conventional approach, since only host name or IP changes, you can establish an internal DNS server, and all application should use the DNS to resolve host name into IP address. So you never have to change host name anymore, this could ease the management using conventional tools like SSH easier too, during development or production. If you want something more fancy, you can do like @R4J mentioned.